# PCL voxel downsampling filter as a function

Tags: 3d, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I would like to use some of the filters as 'functions' so that I use the same filter to different input clouds i.e pass different cloud as an argument. For example the voxel filter (see below) can it be used for different input clouds. If I have cloud A and B, i have to define sor1 and sor2, because I can't use the same sor on both, or maybe it is possible but I don't know how to do it. Can someone share some ideas on this.

```
 // Create the filtering object
 pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> sor;
 sor.setInputCloud (cloud);
 sor.setLeafSize (0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);
 sor.filter (*cloud_filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah just call setInputCloud() again for a new cloud and then filter().

Or you can just put it all in a function and create a new object every time for simplicity.

```
voxelFilter(cloud)
{
   // Create the filtering object
   pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> sor;
   sor.setInputCloud (cloud);
   sor.setLeafSize (0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);
   sor.filter (*cloud_filtered);
   return cloud_filtered;
}
```